# Tikzpicture in table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I would like to center the tikzpicture in first column. In the output, the graph  alignment is different for rows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt]
\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}
\newcounter{Angle}
\textwidth 5.55in
\textheight 7.35in

\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{|b|lc|lc|lc|} 
\hline
G & \multicolumn{2}{c}{cr(G+nK_{1})} \vline & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{cr(G+P_{n})}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {cr(G+C_{n})}  \\ 
\hline 

%enter first row%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\   \hline

%%%%Entering second row%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
    \path
        (a) edge (c)
\end{tikzpicture}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\  \hline

%%%%Entering third row%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
    \path
        (a) edge (c)
        (b) edge (d)
\end{tikzpicture}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\   \hline

 \end{array}\]
\]
\begin{center}
\caption {Summary of crossing numbers for $G+nK_{1}$, $G+P_{n}$ and $G+C_{n}$.}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a couple things going on here that could use some fixing.  (1) You're calling several packages multiple times.  (2)  You're trying to sue a `dvips` driver with TikZ which will eventually lead to problems.  (3) The compilation routes for `pstricks` and TikZ can often be at odds with one another.  (4) Math environments do not like empty lines in them.

Comment: I have edit the question.but the problems remain.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

You can insert your `tikzpicture`s in `minipage`s

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt}}
%\tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt]
\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}
\newcounter{Angle}
\textwidth 5.55in
\textheight 7.35in

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{|c|lc|lc|lc|} % a table with three centered columns separated by vertical lines
\hline
G & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{cr(G+nK_{1})} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{cr(G+P_{n})}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {cr(G+C_{n})}  \\
\hline % a horizontal line to separate the headings (graphs) from the body (vertices)
%enter first row%
\begin{minipage}{0.92cm}
\vspace*{3pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\vspace*{3pt}
\end{minipage}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\   \hline
%%%%Entering second row%%%%
\begin{minipage}{0.92cm}
\vspace*{3pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
    \path
        (a) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\vspace*{3pt}
\end{minipage}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\  \hline
%%%%Entering third row%%%%
\begin{minipage}{0.92cm}
\vspace*{3pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
    \path
        (a) edge (c)
        (b) edge (d);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\vspace*{3pt}
\end{minipage}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\   \hline
 \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

P.S: there were some errors in your code that I've corrected...

- The `b` specifier for array columns does not exists.
- `\path`s must end with `;`
- Use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`. See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/27635) for info.
- Use `|` inside `\multicolumn` instead of `\vline` outside it.

Comment: It would be great to provide some explanation about the errors; side note: it is better to exploit [`tikzset` rather than `tikzstyle`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Yes, thanks. Added some hints.

Comment: @karlkoeller Thank you very much..problem solved!

Comment: @user42789 Glad it helped. Remember that you can accept the answer, if you want. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: @karlkoeller +1 again for you edit and your answer. Greetings.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you. I've made a query to find your own posts affected by the bug. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7303/27635.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the `tikzpicture` in a nested `tabular`, which will provide the vertical alignment. Some more height must be added to cells, which I do by locally changing `\extrarowheight`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{vertex/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=6pt}}
\newcommand{\vertex}{\node[vertex]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{12pt}
$\begin{array}{|c|lc|lc|lc|} 
\hline
G & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{cr(G+nK_{1})} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{cr(G+P_{n})}   &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|} {cr(G+C_{n})}  \\ 
\hline 

%enter first row%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\   \hline
%%%%Entering second row%%%%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
    \path
        (a) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\  \hline

%%%%Entering third row%%%%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm]
    \vertex (a) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex (b) at (1,0) {};
    \vertex (c) at (0,1) {};
    \vertex (d) at (1,1) {};
    \path
        (a) edge (c)
        (b) edge (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
& Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 1 & Z(4,n) & n\geq 3 \\   \hline

\end{array}$
\caption {Summary of crossing numbers for $G+nK_{1}$, $G+P_{n}$ and $G+C_{n}$.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The whole construction should be in a `table` environment, probably. No `\[...\]`, in this case, although it doesn't really make a big difference. I used `\centering` instead.

[image]